# In the reflog, how to know if a reset is a soft, mixed or hard one?

Tags: git

I did a commit and then a mixed reset in my repository. Worked a few files more and didn't commit it. One day later, my changes were gone (probably someone else in the team). So I've checked my reflog and it showed this:

```
82da9af HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD
82da9af HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to HEAD
82da9af HEAD@{2}: reset: moving to HEAD~1
e0e4ee0 HEAD@{3}: commit: *badcommit*
```

So, the question in focus here: how do I know if I did a mixed reset or perhaps unknowingly a hard one?

Bonus question: why it appears three times? (yesterday showed only one of those). By the SHA, they must be the same I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, the question in focus here: how do I know if I did a mixed reset or perhaps unknowingly a hard one?

This information is not saved anywhere.  It might be nice if the reflog message included the `git reset` arguments, but it does not.

> Bonus question: why it appears three times?

Someone or something ran it several more times.  Note that some higher level Git commands, such as `git stash`, use lower-level Git commands, such as `git reset`, and hence generate a lot of reflog noise.

Comment: thanks @torek . testing in a blank repository, I saw that effect of `git stash` you mention, and even in a reset mixed. As for the SHA, its probably because I didn't specify a commit